# Implementing method chaining to get specific data from JSON

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework

#### Here is my table in RDBMS.

```
╔═════╦═════╦══════╗
║ FAT ║ SNF ║ RATE ║
╠═════╬═════╬══════╣
║   3 ║   7 ║   10 ║
║   3 ║   8 ║   11 ║
║   3 ║   9 ║   12 ║
║   4 ║   7 ║   13 ║
║   4 ║   8 ║   14 ║
║   4 ║   9 ║   15 ║
╚═════╩═════╩══════╝
```

Now, I want to get ***rate*** using syntax as below.

```
rate = fat(3).snf(8).rate();
//rate should be 11.
```

So, how to make **JSON** version of above table to get data in typescript using above syntax. Please specify **JSON** and **Typescript** implementation.

I'm using PouchDb and Ionic.